# Animating grid cells

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I want to make an animation where one object would move from one grid cell to another. I tried calculating the positions of the objects but that didn't work (it gave me wrong values). Here's the code if anyone interested:

```
Point locationToScreen = (((e.Source as Button).Content as Viewbox).Child as Label).PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));

PresentationSource source = PresentationSource.FromVisual((((e.Source as Button).Content as Viewbox).Child as Label));
Point pt = source.CompositionTarget.TransformFromDevice.Transform(locationToScreen);

Point a = (letters.Children[_words[_index].Index] as TextBlock).PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));

PresentationSource sos = PresentationSource.FromVisual((letters.Children[_words[_index].Index] as TextBlock));
Point pt2 = sos.CompositionTarget.TransformFromDevice.Transform(a);

TranslateTransform tt = new TranslateTransform();
(((e.Source as Button).Content as Viewbox).Child as Label).RenderTransform = tt;
DoubleAnimation da1 = new DoubleAnimation(0, -(pt.Y - pt2.Y)/2, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)));
DoubleAnimation da2 = new DoubleAnimation(0, -(pt.X - pt2.X)/2, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)));
tt.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.YProperty, da1);
tt.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, da2);
```

So how should I do this? Is there any simple way to move object from one container to another?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need animate kind of 1000 objects simultaneously it definitely better that you create a **new** UI element which appears on top of `Source` element and moves till `Destination` element, after animation finished that element disappears and `Source` and `Destination` elements properties changes as requested.

I personally think that it's easier to use XAML, to me it seems more clear . Here is an example of use: [Animation XAML](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/XAMLAnimation04042007191109PM/XAMLAnimation.aspx)

The basic idea is, declare animation under your `TextBlock` tag and bind it to some dependency property that change of which will launch an animation in desired moment.

Comment: Yes, it's only gonna be 1 object. But I don't really understand what do you mean by saying "bind it to some dependency property".. Maybe you could give me some simple example?